# Making video to interact with html elements

Tags: html, video

The point is to create a intro where video characters interact with HTML elements presented on the page.

Not sure if this can be done, if it can, then can one please drop some orientations about how can we integrate a video file with html elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so with `JW Player`, for example. You can manipulate with your html when the video reach some points. 
See the event `onTime` in the [documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference)